# How do I edit a write-protected file?

Tags: sudo, read-only

I downloaded the [*Garfield* toolkit](https://garfieldpp.web.cern.ch/garfieldpp/) in the /opt/applications folder. Some examples are present inside the folders which I downloaded with the toolkit, and I want to modify some code inside of them (without subscribing it). I copied the Example folder to the home directory (using `sudo`) but the files are still write-protected, is there a way in which i can modify the copy of my example?

EDIT:
If I inspect the file which I want to modify, I obtain this:

```
$ ls Examples/AliceTPC/plot_gas.C -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1350 mag 25 12:03 Examples/AliceTPC/plot_gas.C
```

The username I use is lorenzo

Comment: ... you should have copied it **without** using `sudo`

Comment: You can `sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) Examples/`.

Comment: In order to receive better answers and not just suggestions please include more information about the file(s) you may wish to edit. Please run `ls /opt/applications/FILENAME -la` (just make sure you change FILENAME with the file you wish to inspect) and let us know what is the username you use for your system, you can run `who am i` in a terminal and include that information in your question. Please make sure you have your user password at hand in order to run any super user procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The file seems to be owned by root, so first we need to make sure the file is owned by **lorenzo**. We need to do it as mentioned by [@waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator), using this more specific command in a terminal:

```
sudo chown lorenzo:lorenzo Examples/AliceTPC/plot_gas.C
```

But please make sure you need only this file to be owned by *lorenzo*. If you need the whole AliceTPC folder to be owned by *lorenzo*, then run something like this:

```
sudo chown lorenzo:lorenzo Examples/AliceTPC/* -R
```

This will recursively change the owner to folder itself and every single file inside the folder.

That might not be sufficient and you yet need to check the file's permissions with something like this:

**WAIT: Just make sure you run this in the proper files.**

```
chmod 777 FILENAME
```

Or this for every single file.

```
chmod 777 *
```

If the element we wish to change permissions is a folder then run:

```
chmod 777 AliceTPC -R
```

Then you can edit any file with your favorite text editor, in example:

```
nano plot_gas.C
```

No need to use `sudo` to do this, unless the files **should** be root owned.

**Please make sure you use the proper file permissions when running the `chmod` command on your files.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with:

```
sudo chown <username> <file or directory name>
```